# Closing gaps labeled matrix

Tags: python, scipy

I have an labeled numpy array with gaps between, for example:

```
a = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,3,1],[1,5,1]])
```

which I want to close, like:

```
a = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,2,1],[1,3,1]])
```

How can I do this? When I use scipy.ndimage.measurements.label I get the following:

```
a = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])
```

As you can see the problem is I do not really want to relabel the matrix. Just close the gaps between.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can do that, using `np.unique` with the `return_inverse` parameter:

```
In [30]: a
Out[30]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 3, 1],
       [1, 5, 1]])

In [31]: u, inv = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)

In [32]: b = (inv + u[0]).reshape(a.shape)

In [33]: b
Out[33]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 1],
       [1, 3, 1]])
```